# Computing distance between mouse and points in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm just messing around and want to calculate the distances between the mouse position in a canvas and different parts of the canvas (center, top right, top left, etc.). 
Though, with the code I currently have it either displays "NaN" or something completely inaccurate instead of the actual distances.There are no errors. Here's my code(It's probably super inefficient because I'm kind of new to coding):

```
var Canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = Canvas.getContext('2d');
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

//cncs stands for corners and center
var cncs = {
    "center": {
        "x": Canvas.clientWidth/2,
        "y": Canvas.clientHeight/2
    },
    "topleft": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    },
    "topright": {
        "x": Canvas.clientWidth,
        "y": 0
    },
    "bottomleft": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": Canvas.clientHeight
    },
    "bottomright": {
        "x": Canvas.clientWidth,
        "y": Cache.clientHeight
    }
} 

function update(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Canvas.clientWidth, Canvas.clientHeight);
    drawText();
}
function drawText(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = '15pt Calibri';
    ctx.fillText("MouseX: " + mouseX + ", MouseY: " + mouseY, 0, 15);
    ctx.fillText("Distance from: ", 800 , 15);

    var centerDist = Math.floor(getDistances().center);
    ctx.fillText("Center: " + centerDist, 800, 65);

    var topleftDist = Math.floor(getDistances().topleft);
    ctx.fillText("Top Left: " + topleftDist, 800, 90);

    var toprightDist = Math.floor(getDistances().topright);
    ctx.fillText("Top Right: " + toprightDist, 800, 115);

    var bottomleftDist = Math.floor(getDistances().bottomleft);
    ctx.fillText("Bottom Left: " + bottomleftDist, 800, 140);

    var bottomrightDist = Math.floor(getDistances().bottomright);
    ctx.fillText("Bottom Right: " + bottomrightDist, 800, 165)
}
function getMousePos(e){
    var rect = Canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;
}
Canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    getMousePos(e);
});

function getDistances(){
    return{
       "center": Math.sqrt((cncs.center.x - mouseX)^2 + (cncs.center.y - 
  mouseY)^2),
       "topleft": Math.sqrt((cncs.topleft.x - mouseX)^2 + (cncs.topleft.y - 
mouseY)^2),
       "topright": Math.sqrt((cncs.topright.x - mouseX)^2 + (cncs.topright.y 
- mouseY)^2),
       "bottomleft": Math.sqrt((cncs.bottomleft.x - mouseX)^2 + 
(cncs.bottomleft.y - mouseY)^2),
       "bottomright": Math.sqrt((cncs.bottomright.x - mouseX)^2 + 
(cncs.bottomright.y - mouseY)^2)
    };
}

setInterval(update, 1000/60);
```

Comment: I am sure, everything shows up fine, but the numbers on the right are either "NaN" or innacurate

Comment: I'm on Chrome Version 67, though I'm not sure if its a problem with my browser. 
The center distance in the top right says "NaN" when my mouse is in the top right and bottom left, but works inaccurately (says something other than "NaN").

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the NaNs because my canvas element was too small. I'll write an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `^` isn't exponentiation, but rather the binary xor operator. You can use the `**` operator or `Math.pow()` to raise a number to a power in JS:

```
  function getDistances() {
      return {
          "center": 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(cncs.center.x - mouseX, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(cncs.center.y - mouseY, 2)
              ),
          "topleft": 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(cncs.topleft.x - mouseX, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(cncs.topleft.y - mouseY, 2)
              ),
          "topright": 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(cncs.topright.x - mouseX, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(cncs.topright.y - mouseY, 2)
              ),
          "bottomleft": 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(cncs.bottomleft.x - mouseX, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(cncs.bottomleft.y - mouseY, 2)
              ),
          "bottomright": 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(cncs.bottomright.x - mouseX, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(cncs.bottomright.y - mouseY, 2)
              )
      };
  }
```

Beyond this, `Cache.clientHeight` should be `Canvas.clientHeight`. Lastly, this code suffers from functions that rely on global variables and repeated expensive calculation. I recommend using function parameters to increase encapsulation, make functions reusable and avoid repetition. For example, adding parameters to `getDistances()` results in:

```
const getDistance = (ax, ay, bx, by) => ((ax - bx) ** 2 + (ay - by) ** 2) ** 0.5;
```

And call this with:

```
getDistance(cncs.center.x, cncs.center.y, mouseX, mouseY);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!